# How to open multiple folders with a specific Application (Gemini 2)?

Tags: macos, finder, applescript, folders, automation

This is a supposed to be a simple AppleScript but I have searched many post on stackexchange.com and I cannot find anything that works.

Basically, "Gemini 2" is a duplicate of finder ([macpaw.com/gemini](https://macpaw.com/gemini)). I simply want to add all of the selected folders to open with the "Gemini 2" app but for some reason they are not being added to the application when it opens.

I have tested this script with other apps and it works fine. For some reason it is not working with "Gemini 2" even though I have the correct bundle identifier.

```
tell application "Finder"
   set sel to selection
   if sel is not {} then
       set filepath to item 1 of sel as text --> The path to the one selected item.
       open filepath using application file id "com.macpaw.site.Gemini2" -- bundle identifier of the designated application
   end if
end tell
```

You can check the bundle identifier yourself with the following code in terminal:

```
osascript -e 'id of app "Gemini 2"'
```

Comment: Does Gemini support this at all?

Comment: I suppose it does since when you install the application, it adds a macOS "Service" in "Finder" where you can  "Scan for Duplicates with Gemini 2" on the selected folders. But I do not want to do this manually for every folder. I am trying to create an automated workflow.

Comment: Does the service in Finder work for several folders at once?

Comment: Yes it does. I just tested it right now.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `open alias filepath using...` instead of `open filepath using...`?

Comment: @wch1zpink I have tried it just now and it is still not adding the folders to the application.

Comment: When trying to add **Gemini 2** to the **Library** in **Script Editor** it errors with "Unable to add the item because it is not scriptable." Which means is does not contain an **AppleScript** _dictionary file_ within its _application bundle_ and is not scriptable by **AppleScript**, other then maybe **UI Scripting** or very basic _commands_ in the **Standard Suite**.

Comment: You said, "I simply want to add all of the selected folders to open with the "Gemini 2" app" ... Well if you select _folders_ in **Finder** you can then select from the **Services** menu e.g. **Scan for Duplicates with Gemini 2**, so why do you need to _script_ this?

Comment: BTW I just tested the _code_ in your OP under **macOS Catalina** with **Gemini 2** and it worked without issue, it opened **Gemini 2** with the selected folder in **Finder** in its **UI** ready to click the **Scan for Duplicates** button, so what is the issue you're having?

Comment: Also, if you're running **macOS Catalina** you need to make sure in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Files and Folders** it has **Gemini 2** with a **[√] Named Folder** checkbox checked, where **Named Folder** is the name of the folder to be scanned by **Gemini 2**.

Comment: Okay, after playing around with it a bit more I found that **Gemini 2** is not consistent on how it opens when trying to do it programmatically, sometimes it works, other times it doesn't. The only way to constantly have the selected _folders_ in **Finder** open in **Gemini 2** is to use **Scan for Duplicates with Gemini 2** from the **Services** menu in **Finder**.

Comment: @user3439894 thanks for the effort. I guess I will just have to try something else like manually recording a "watch me do" with automator. I have many folders that I need to search and I do not want to it manually.

Comment: Last ditch: you could try `tell application id "com.macpaw.site.Gemini2" to open location (filepath as alias)`.  So use _Finder_, as you've done, to get the selected item; then, _after_ (**not** inside the _Finder_ `tell` block), you insert that line.  Another option: `do shell script "open " & (quoted form of POSIX path of filepath) & " -b 'com.macpaw.site.Gemini2' "`

Comment: @CjK. Just tried it and nothing. But I got it working by recording an automator workflow.